# Couldn't listen on :::8008: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: matrix-synapse

I am using **"*docker.io/matrixdotorg/synapse:latest-py3*"** docker image, It is working as expected When I run it locally but only when I deploy it to my cluster and having **Couldn't listen on :::8008: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol** error. 
any help?

````
- twisted - 242 - ERROR - - Traceback (most recent call last):

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1356, in startListening

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -     skt = self.createInternetSocket()

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1340, in createInternetSocket

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -     s = base.BasePort.createInternetSocket(self)

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1188, in createInternetSocket

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -     s = socket.socket(self.addressFamily, self.socketType)

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 144, in __init__


- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -     _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - - OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


- twisted - 242 - ERROR - - Traceback (most recent call last):

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/synapse/app/_base.py", line 282, in start

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -     hs.start_listening(listeners)

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/synapse/app/homeserver.py", line 261, in start_listening

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -     self._listener_http(config, listener)

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/synapse/app/homeserver.py", line 154, in _listener_http

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -     reactor=self.get_reactor(),

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/synapse/app/_base.py", line 190, in listen_tcp

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -     check_bind_error(e, address, bind_addresses)

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/synapse/app/__init__.py", line 49, in check_bind_error

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -     raise e

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/synapse/app/_base.py", line 186, in listen_tcp

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -     address

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 495, in listenTCP

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -     p.startListening()

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1363, in startListening

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - -     raise CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le)

- twisted - 242 - ERROR - - twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on :::8008: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol```
`
````

Answer (score 3):

You probably have ipv6 disabled, and the default config is trying to listen on both ipv6 and ipv4.  If you check the `bind_addresses` section of your `/etc/matrix-synapse/homeserver.yaml` config file, you should change `bind_addresses: ['::1', '127.0.0.1']` to `bind_addresses: ['127.0.0.1']`